# Is it the same to use 1) StandardScaler & Classifier vs 2) Pipeline(Scalar, Classifier)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest

Does running a standard scaler and then a classifier give the same result as using a pipeline?

Hi, I have a classification problem and trying to scale the X variables using scikit learn's StandardScaler(). I see two options of doing this, should they in theory yield the same result? Because I am getting better precision score on my test data set when I use option (1).

(1)

```
scalar = StandardScaler()
xtrain_ = scalar.fit_transform(xtrain)
RFC = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
RFC.fit(xtrain. ytrain)

xtest_ = scalar.transform(xtest)
score = cross_val_score(RFC, xtest_, ytest,cv=10, scoring ='precision')
```

(2)

```
RFCs = Pipeline([("scale", StandardScaler()), ("rf", RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100))])
RFCs.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
scores = cross_val_score(RFCs, xytest, ytest, cv=10, scoring='precision')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your option number 2 uses a different data set (`xytest`) than your version number (1), which uses `xtest`. Furthermore, your crossvalidation should include the training, not only the prediction.

Apart from that they should be the same, while I advice you to use pipelines.